# Select Unique records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table with multi-valued fields (Deposits, Tax1 and tax2) as below:

```
ID   Account_Number    Plan       Deposits       Tax1            Tax2

10   123456            PRINC10      4;4       4256.45;1567.45  4256.45;1567.45


11   123456            KrINC11      4;4       4256.45;1567.45  4256.45;1567.45
```

I have separated multi valued fields using DelimiterSplit8K  table valued function from SQL Servercentral.com.

The code i used to seperate the multivalued fields to separate rows is below:

```
 Select [ID], [account_number], [Plan], [Deposits], [Tax1], [Tax2]
 From MVTable
 Cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(MVTable.Deposits, ';') as Depositlist
 Cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(MVTable.Tax1, ';') as Tax1List
 Cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(MVTable.Tax2, ';') as Tax2List
  `enter code here`Where DepositList.Itemnumber = Tax1list.itemnumber
  and Depositlist.itemnumber = Tax2list.itemnumber
```

But the data i received has some duplicates

```
ID   account_number     Plan     Deposits   Tax1         Tax2 

10   123456             PRINC10    4        4256.45     4256.45

10   123456             PRINC10    4        1567.45     1567.45

11   123456             KrINC11    4        4256.45     4256.45

11   123456             KrINC11    4        1567.45     1567.45
```

The desired result should be as below, we only want one plan field for each account number/id fields and Tax1 and Tax2 fields appropriately.

```
ID   account_number     Plan     Deposits   Tax1         Tax2 

10   123456             PRINC10    4        4256.45     4256.45

11   123456             KrINC11    4        1567.45     1567.45
```

Comment: Thanks John @john

Comment: Ok, I will add more reason behind why i need this result. Thanks @John

Comment: This isn't clear.  The rows in your example table are unique.  What criteria are you using to decide what you need in your results?

Comment: What if the last row - Mtg   3   3    3 was not there in your sample data?

Comment: Are you only wanting to keep rows where `Col1 = Col2 AND col2 = Col3 AND col1 = max(col1) (for this DNO)`? That's the only logic I can divine from this sample data/desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit post with my complete reason why i need that result.

Comment: Why your expected result is not: cc,1,1,1 sales,2,2,2 mtg,3,3,3

Comment: I had to change question entirely to clearly explain what i am trying to achieve. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I still don't see how you know which row is the correct row to keep for your results.

Comment: How you calculate Tax1 & Tax2?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a different way of splitting the values:

```
with cte as (
      select id, account_number, plan,
             convert(varchar(max), left(deposits, charindex(';', deposits + ';') - 1)) as deposit,
             convert(varchar(max), left(tax2, charindex(';', tax2 + ';') - 1)) as tax1,
             convert(varchar(max), left(tax2, charindex(';', tax2 + ';') - 1)) as tax2,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(deposits, 1, charindex(';', deposits + ';'), '')) as deposit_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(tax1, 1, charindex(';', tax1 + ';'), '')) as tax1_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(tax2, 1, charindex(';', tax2 + ';'), '')) as tax2_rest
      from t
      union all
      select id, account_number, plan,
             convert(varchar(max), left(deposit_rest, charindex(';', deposit_rest + ';') - 1)) as deposit,
             convert(varchar(max), left(tax2_rest, charindex(';', tax2_rest + ';') - 1)) as tax1,
             convert(varchar(max), left(tax2_rest, charindex(';', tax2_rest + ';') - 1)) as tax2,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(deposit_rest, 1, charindex(';', deposit_rest + ';'), '')) as deposit_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(tax1_rest, 1, charindex(';', tax1_rest + ';'), '')) as tax1_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(tax2_rest, 1, charindex(';', tax2_rest + ';'), '')) as tax2_rest
       from cte
       where deposit_rest <> ''
      )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab2e44676d6417ef64a275b2632dfc39) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for taking time and responding to my question, I have multi valued fields like with 10's of numbers in it. For example in Deposits field there is data as 1;4;3;2;3;4;4;5;6;7;7 for some records. That is the reason i went with TVF Delimitedsplit8k.

Comment: @prathapkasthuri . . . The `join`s don't work.  That's why I'm suggesting a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one plan per acc_number/id and not caring about `tax1` and `tax2`, then you can use this,

```
select id, account_number, [plan],
convert(varchar(max), left(deposits, charindex(';', deposits) - 1)) as deposit,
convert(varchar(max), left(tax2, charindex(';', tax2) - 1)) as tax1,
convert(varchar(max), left(tax2, charindex(';', tax2) - 1)) as tax2
from ##t
```

Output looks like,

```
id  account_number  plan    deposit tax1        tax2
10  123456          PRINC10     4   4256.45     4256.45
11  123456          KrINC11     4   4256.45     4256.45
```

Comment: Thanks @Pugal for taking time and responding to my post. But i do require Tax1 and Tax2 fields appropriately.  Please see my desired result set in my post.

Comment: @prathapkasthuri You did said about `plan` only. which logic was used for selecting that rows?